# How to implement developer authenticated identities in Unity3d using aws cognito identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement developer authenticated Identities in Unity using PHP server and aws cognito Identity. I used the same code given in AWS documentation which is:

```
  public class DeveloperAuthenticatedCredentials : CognitoAWSCredentials  
 {
      const string PROVIDER_NAME = "login.xyz.abc";
      const string IDENTITY_POOL = "IDENTITY_POOL_ID";
      static readonly RegionEndpoint REGION = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
      private string login = null;


   public DeveloperAuthenticatedCredentials(string loginAlias)
    : base(IDENTITY_POOL, REGION)
    {
        login = loginAlias;
    }

    protected override IdentityState RefreshIdentity()
    {
        IdentityState state = null;
        ManualResetEvent waitLock = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        MainThreadDispatcher.ExecuteCoroutineOnMainThread(ContactProvider((s) =>
        {
            state = s;
            waitLock.Set();
        }));
        waitLock.WaitOne();
        return state;
    }

    IEnumerator ContactProvider(Action<IdentityState> callback)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("[http://example.com/?username=][1]"+login);
        yield return www;
        string response = www.text;

        JsonData json = JsonMapper.ToObject(response);

        string identityId = json["IdentityId"].ToString();
        string token = json["Token"].ToString();

        IdentityState state = new IdentityState(identityId, PROVIDER_NAME, token, false);
        callback(state);
    }
}
```

Then I created object for this class by passing argument.Then called AddLogin by passing credentials.

```
 DeveloperAuthenticatedCredentials Credentials = new DeveloperAuthenticatedCredentials("qwer");
 DAC.AddLogin("login.xyz.abc",token);
```

When token is created in server, an identity is generated. And one more unauthenticated identity is created when I try to synchronize data using cognito sync. I have also attached the policy "AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities" to both the auth and unauth roles of the identity pool.Please help me merge the two identities that are being generated. Thanks in advance.